# Couldn't install Xamarin in VIsual Studio 2017

Tags: xamarin

I tried to install Xamarin in Visual Studio 2017.
It shows one error:
"JavaJDKV2 could not be installed."
Xamarin has been added to my Visual Studio, but I can't use it,
when I start new project, that message appears and the project can not be created.
Any ideas or workarounds?

Comment: tell the steps you followed to install xamarin... and tell where you got the error...

Comment: 1. I downloaded VisualStudioInstaller_xxxx.exe as it reads the documentation of Xamarin.
2. When Installing I select Modify (to add Xamarin to a VIsual Studio already installed).
3. The error appears when the installation ends.

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/tour You may also want to check http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask, and how to create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.